# How can I utilize existing UI for my plugin's control panel views?

Tags: templating, plugin-development, control-panel

I'm new to building plugins and I need to make templates for the control panel. How can I use existing Craft UI components to keep things consistent and save myself from having to rebuild everything?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have a look in **craft/app/templates** for tons of great, easily-reusable examples that make up the existing control panel! They may not be documented, but there's a whole lot of quality stuff there.

You may also want to consider using macros from **craft/app/templates/_includes** ([Craft TemplatesService doc](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/apis/templatesservice), [Twig macro doc](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/macro.html)), which will go a long way toward good DRY templates.

Bonus: this is also a great way to learn clever ways of doing things in Twig, like breadcrumbs for example. P&T builds excellent stuff, so there's lots to learn from and steal whether it's for the control panel or the front end.

Comment: I would point out the macros folder if he's building forms in the Control Panel. And a future thought, it would be great if some of this was documented somewhere. Especially the element layouts and form macros.

Comment: There I go again, learning something even in a closed-loop self-question! Thanks Bryan.

Comment: Those macros are sticking with you, heh @Matt?

Comment: @Christian You bet! In just a little while, I'll be able to pretend I knew all along.

Comment: @Matt I meant over here at SE, actually. Didn't know how to better express that in english! O.o

Comment: @ChristianSeelbach No worries, I can *only* express things in English. Or some really awful Spanish or French.

Comment: Any pro-tips for how to do this in Craft 3, @MattStein?

Comment: Same basic advice @RobErskine! Make a pot of coffee, clone https://github.com/craftcms/cms, and start digging around `src/templates`. The past few years have also seen a number of first-party plugins worth checking out: https://github.com/craftcms. A look under the hood at any P&T work is guaranteed to be 100% Crafty.